# Modelling the tail only

Tags: probability, modeling, extreme-value

I'm trying to model a real-world random variable that behaves approximately as a Gaussian, so a Normal distribution fit is reasonable but far from perfect.

However, I only care about its tail, that is, I only care about finding $x$ such as $P(X > x) < p$, with $p$  anywhere between 1% and 5%. I'm modelling the random variable as $X\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$, with parameters estimated from all the samples.

I tried to search for specific ways to handle this and I got a lot of results regarding Extreme Value Theory, but it seems to apply mostly to even smaller probabilities than I care or to a heavy-tailed distributions, which is not my case.

Any pointers?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "model" and "estimation."  Do you have any data?  Are you trying to use them to fit the upper tail of a distribution? If so, why?--what information do you hope to derive from that fit or what further analyses will you do with it?  What additional subject-matter information might there be about how the upper tail ought to look?

Comment: Yes, I have a lot of data, but it is divided in groups, and each group only contains a small amount of the total data (100 to a 1000 samples each). For each group I try to model it as a Normal distribution, and estimate its parameters from the group samples. The Normal assumption is reasonable, but there is some skewness and less kurtosis than a true Gaussian. What I'm trying to find out is the threshold where there is a small probability (1-5%) of exceeding it. With my Gaussian model I can readily calculate it using standard probability. That is the best I can explain.

Comment: I rewrote the original post a bit so it would be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The devil, as they say, is in the tails. Many have been led to misleading and wrong conclusions by using an easy-to-handle modeling tactic (e.g. the Normal!), which failed them spectacularly when the time came to do statistical inference -which mostly depends on what happens in the tails -and the empirical distribution of the data may have looked adequately normal in its "main body", but a different story in the tails.  And you are exclusively concerned with the tails.

In a comment, you mention that you have some skewness, but most importantly, *negative* excess kurtosis. Not many distributions supported on the real line exhibit negative excess kurtosis. In fact the first that comes to mind is the ["Generalized Normal Distribution"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_power_distribution). It can exhibit negative excess kurtosis if the new parameter (instead of the square) is sufficiently large. Its second version can also handle skewness. But you should find a way to calculate the relevant probabilities - since they will depend on the value of this new parameter, I doubt that any tables already calculated by others will match your case.